# Is it possible in Profibus DP that slaves can talk each other?

Tags: communication, protocol, network, serial-bus

I could not understand what Profibus DP is. Is it only I/O system which is controlled with a PLC or is it a complete bus system which controls the data traffic? If the second, I would like to ask if there is a possibility that slaves can communicate each other and is it possible to have multiple masters?

Comment: You might want to link to the relevant Profibus documentation and explain which sections you don't understand.

Comment: @user_1818839 actually my question is that CANBUS have own controller , driver and physical layer interface and forms a complete system. For the Profibus, I couldn't find any info about controller. In all applications I see that is connected to controller(main controller) which is also master. I would like to understand it is just an interface between PLC and field devices. So, it is not a specific part of some documentation, just use case that I couldn not understand if it is a alternative of CAN or similar multidrop buses- It uses RS-485 in Physical Layer so what Profibus-DP actually is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profibus and https://www.profibus.com/download/?tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=technology%3APROFIBUS appear to have these answers.